USDT received from Binance, but impossible to send or swap them
I made a withdrawal of USDT from binance to my personal wallet which I use daily for defi etc.
Together with this "new" USDT received from Binance, I have like 16 usdt on my wallet, and these can be normally swapped, sent, and they are "visible" from raydium, jupiter etc. And this is true for any other token I have on the wallet.
These new USDT instead, received from binance, are impossible to send, swap, and they are invisible on raydium, jupiter etc.
I have enough SOL to pay fees, since I have 0.13 SOL.
I've already spoken a lot with binance support, they say it's not their fault.

Solved by myself: found out I had to migrate to ATA tokens, from old raydium page.
Binance support wasn't able to tell me the solutions. Case closed
